# Nothing returned when rending data to the screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

The code below is suppose to render data to the screen if data exists in the state. In the `renderCards()` function, if I do not `.map` over the state, the return method renders Text (i.e. "Match"), cool. Now when I map over the state and it should return text to the screen according to how ever many elements are in the array, but in this case it does not return anything. I do not receive any errors or warnings when render the component.

Any thoughts on this?

```
renderCards(){
    if(this.state.leagueMatchesInfo != null){
        console.log("rendering cards")
        return this.state.leagueMatchesInfo.map(match => {
        //  console.log(match)
            // return (
                <View>
                    <Text>Match</Text>
                </View>
            // );
        });
    }

}



render(){

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            {this.renderCards()}
        </ScrollView>    
        );
}
```

Comment: `return` the components from map function. Seems like you have commented out the `return` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `return` the `map` elements as well.

```
renderCards(){
    if(this.state.leagueMatchesInfo != null){
        console.log("rendering cards")
        return this.state.leagueMatchesInfo.map(match => {
        //  console.log(match)
             return (
                <View>
                    <Text>Match</Text>
                </View>
             );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you my good sir. any chance you could look at this question? Me and my partner are new to react-native, and having a problem.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773460/setting-state-when-using-a-map-function

Answer (score 0):

You can either try `return` from the map function:

```
renderCards(){
    if(this.state.leagueMatchesInfo != null){
        console.log("rendering cards")
        return this.state.leagueMatchesInfo.map(match => {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>Match</Text>
                </View>
            );
        });
    }

}
```

or if you only have element, (which react insists that you do):

```
renderCards(){
    if(this.state.leagueMatchesInfo != null){
        console.log("rendering cards")
        return this.state.leagueMatchesInfo.map(match => 
          (
            <View>
              <Text>Match</Text>
           </View>
           )
        );
    }

}
```

```js
const array = [1,2,3];
class App extends React.Component {
  implicitReturn() {
    return array.map(one=>(
      <div>
        <p>Implicit Return</p>
      </div>
    )
    );
  }
  explicitReturn() {
    return array.map(one=>{
      return (
        <div>
          <p>Explicit Return</p>
        </div>
      )
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.implicitReturn()}
        {this.explicitReturn()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```