# setting state when using a .map function

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

I think I may running into a callback hell type scenario or this may be an issue with scope. I want setState with `allLeagues` array once the .map function is finished running. Problem is, when the `.map` function is done and `this.setState({leagueAL: allLeagues)}` is ran, the state is set to an empty array. I do not want to run `this.setState` inside the .map and set it multiple times. Any thoughts on how I can make the data persist into the state?

```
getLeagueMatches = () => {
            let allLeagues = []
            if(this.state.leagueMatchesInfo != null){
                this.state.leagueMatchesInfo.map((league, id) => {
                    let leagueID = league.league_id;
                    fetch(`https://apifootball.com/api/?action=get_events&from=2017-09-11&to=2017-09-11&league_id=${leagueID}&APIkey=<APIKey>`)
                        .then(res => res.json())
                            .then(event => {
                                //console.log(event)
                                if(event.error){
                                    //console.log(event.error)
                                }else{
                                    league.matches = true;
                                    //console.log(league)
                                    allLeagues = [...allLeagues, league]
                                }
                            })
                            console.log(allLeagues)

                 })
                 this.setState({
                     leagueAL: allLeagues
                 })
            }//end if(65)    
        };//end renderItem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array. You'll need to catch it in a variable. In map, you should have a function that does something on each element.

`allLeagues = this.state.leagueMatchesInfo.map((league, id) => {
    ...
}
this.setState({
    leagueAL: allLeagues
})`

Then setState after the map.

Comment: Ahh that's right! `.map()` returns a new array. That fact escaped my mind. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not updating the `allLeagues` array until the promises have resolved. However, `setState` is being called before any of this even happens.

I would look into something like `Promise.all()`. Then you can create an array of promises with each call to `fetch`. Then you can call `.then` off your `Promise.all()` and set the state within the `.then`.

Comment: so yes `.map()` returned a brand new array of Promises which I then had to use `Promise.all()` in effort to resolve it. Thanks man !