# react native cant update state array in function

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, ecmascript-6

Im trying to push object into a state array in a function.But i cant, when i debug my array it is still empty..`this.state = {
            searchArray : [],}`
here is my function

```
doSearch = (textinput) => {
        let arrSearch = this.state.searchArray
        //iterate model object
        this.state.models[this.props.sexeModel].map(
            (model) => {
                let idmodel = model.id
                //check if typed text is included in model name
                if(model.nom.includes(textinput.SearchText)){
                    if(textinput.SearchText.length !== 0) {
                        //Checking if Search arr is empty
                        if(arrSearch.length === 0) {
                            let stateArray = this.state.searchArray
                            let joined = stateArray.concat(model)
                            this.setState({ searchArray: joined }) // CANT UPDATE HERE 
                        } else {
                            arrSearch.map((modelSearch) => {
                                if(modelSearch.id == idmodel) {
                                    console.log("Do not insert")
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Insert")
                                    let joined = arrSearch.concat(model)
                                     this.setState({ arrSearch: joined })// CANTE UPDATE HERE
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("include but empty")
                        this.setState({searchArray:[]}) //CANT UPDATE HERE
                    }

                } else {
                    console.log("not included")
                    this.setState({searchArray:[]}) // CANT UPDATE HERE
                }
            }
        )
}
```

I can update a basic string or int/float state value in this function but not an array.Why ?
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Did you try `let stateArray = this.state.searchArray.slice()`? copying the array instead of using the reference.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773460/setting-state-when-using-a-map-function . I think you need to call setState() after your map.

Comment: Tried both of your solution but array still wont change..